# What's the listener with Skype Java API to get Group message?

Tags: java, skype, groupchat

I search how to have listener like ChatMessageListener but for groups...
For this I use skype java api 1.6.

So I want to have this:

```
@Override
public void chatMessageReceived(ChatMessage arg0) throws SkypeException {
    ...
}

@Override
public void chatMessageSent(ChatMessage arg0) throws SkypeException {
    ...
}
```

But it's not working for Skype Groups :(

So **how to have this for listeners of Skype Groups?**